# What does it change to declare a constant above or bellow a React functional component?

Tags: reactjs, variables, components, declaration, react-lifecycle

My question is what does it change to declare a constant above or bellow a React functional component (or a class component also) ?
for example what is the difference if I do :

```
     const myName = "Olivier";
        const myReactComponent = () => {
      const whatsMyName = (name) => console.log(name);
       whatsMyName(myName);
      return(<div></div>); 
    }
```

OR

```
       const myReactComponent = () => {
       const myName = "Olivier";

      const whatsMyName = (name) => console.log(name);
       whatsMyName(myName);
      return(<div></div>); 
    }
```

If someone could explain to me the difference It would be great !
Also for example Could I move the whatsMyName function above also ?
My guess is that it has to do with react Life Cycles .
Thanks so much !

Answer (score 2):

The main difference comes down to re-rendering.

Variables set outside of the component will not trigger a re-render, whereas those that are set inside a component will trigger a re-render.

In general you wouldn't set a constant inside of a component for this reason... if you have a constant, put it in a constants file and call as needed - that way you won't have any unintended re-renders.

If you need the variable to update, then use the `useState` hook to manage this:

`const [name, setName] = useState('Tom');`

When you update `name` using `setName('New Name')` it will trigger a re-render.